# SQL SUM used in WHERE from LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, where-clause

This is my SQL code

```
SELECT d.*,
       SUM(k.active) AS sumactive
FROM devices AS d
LEFT JOIN devicekits AS dk ON dk.id_device = d.id
LEFT JOIN kits AS k ON k.id = dk.id_kit
WHERE sumactive = 0
GROUP BY d.id;
```

But if i do this i get this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'sumactive' in 'where clause'
```

Why have I no access to sumactive in the Where clause?

If there is a way to do it easier with Laravel Relationship, please go ahead.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and see about HAVING

Comment: where cannot using columns created with aliases, either use Having or use SUM(k.active)=0

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT d.*, SUM(k.active) as sumactive 
FROM devices AS d 
LEFT JOIN devicekits AS dk ON dk.id_device = d.id 
LEFT JOIN kits as k ON k.id = dk.id_kit
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING sumactive = 0;
```

It's very clear what the error code says. The alias cannot be used in WHERE.

Also, since you use an aggregate function, you need HAVING.

Comment: The next Problem i have, some sumactive ar NULL, but i can't do having sumactive = NULL. I also tried `SUM(CASE WHEN sumactive is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` but it will add +1 to each entry, if its multiple time in database

Comment: I tried `HAVING sumactive IS NULL OR 0`, it wont work

Comment: SUM(COALESCE(k.active,0)). Even better, change the field to DEFAULT 0